# In terminal SSH typing delay

Tags: command-line, ssh

when i'm connecting to a remote PC via terminal and ssh, sometimes the screen freezes, taking some seconds do show what i'm typing. Tried to connect via ethernet but still happens.
Any hints?

Comment: You are probably just experiencing the latency between the client and the server. What you type will only appear on the screen once the data has gone round trip. The server has to receive your input, interpret it, and send it back to you.

Comment: @Nmath I understand your point, but I'm on the same network, and the delay time varies from none to many seconds in what seems to be random events

Comment: Connect with `ssh -v ...` to get more information. How are you "on the same network"? Wired/WiFi? Hub/Switch? What versions of which Operating Systems are running at each end? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: same network means, same hub, wired. I'll try ssh -v